# How to check if two itemIndex is same in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drag and drop code in which `ROUNDBOX` can be dragged and dropped to `RECTANGULARBOX` in which `IMAGEnumber` in rectangularbox is same as `ROUNDBOXdigit`.

I have taken the itemIndex of the dragged item to `X`
`x=document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;`

and itemIndex of Imagenumber to`Y`
`y=tempimages[randomIndex].index;`

**I want to check a condition if(x==y) if only then it allows drop.**

But im not able check the condition,

How to change my code to achieve this property? where is the mistake

```js
var randomIndex;
var array2 = [];
var item;
var tempimages = [];
var notesselected = [];
 
var items = [
{label:'1',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
{label:'2',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'},
{label:'3',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'},
{label:'4',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'},
{label:'5',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'},
{label:'6',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'},
{label:'7',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'},
{label:'8',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'},
{label:'9',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'}];

var notes = [
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4',                                                                                  'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
];


array2 = items.slice();
notes2 = notes.slice();

boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

function rvalue() 
{
 
for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++)
{
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() *array2.length)

item = array2[randomIndex];

tempimages.push({data: item,index: randomIndex });
notesselected.push({data: notes2[randomIndex],index: randomIndex});
 
boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')'; 

array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
notes2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
}
}


function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}



function drop(ev) {

ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
var el = document.getElementById(data);
  
var x=document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
if(typeof tempimages[randomIndex] !== 'undefined') 
{ var y = tempimages[randomIndex].index; }
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
if(x==y)
{

ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundImage = 'initial';
ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';

var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
item = this.item;
var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;
tempimages.splice(arrayvalue, 1);
if (tempimages.length == 0) {
    rvalue();
    }
displayAllImages();
 
}
}
function displayAllImages()
{
if (tempimages.length == 0) 
{
rvalue();
}

var arr2=notesselected;
item = arr2.shift();
image = document.getElementById('slide');
image.src =item.data;
image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;
}

$(function() {

  displayAllImages();

});
```

```css
.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.3vh;
  left: 40.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 23.0vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
<div class="containerr">
<div class="pic" id="content">
<div id="container">


<div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
 <p name="values"></p>
</div>
<div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
 <p name="values"></p>
</div>
<div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
  <p name="values"></p>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, just wondering - you've got the jQuery link in your snippet, but you're not using it in your Javascript - any reason for this?

Comment: @jack-bashford   it is used for displayImages() function